# Error while installing Jitsi

Tags: apt, software-installation, uninstall

I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to Ubuntu. I wanted to install Jitsi because I didn't know there's a web application. While installing I came across an error which I tried to resolve but didn't managed to. And because I was told it was accessible via browser I ignored it. Now I want to customize my terminal but when trying to install new packages there is the following error:

```
The given hostname does not exist in the config
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-prosody (--configure):
 installed jitsi-meet-prosody package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jitsi-meet:
 jitsi-meet depends on jitsi-meet-prosody (= 1.0.3928-1); however:
  Package jitsi-meet-prosody is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jitsi-meet-turnserver:
 jitsi-meet-turnserver depends on jitsi-meet-prosody; however:
  Package jitsi-meet-prosody is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-turnserver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-prosody
 jitsi-meet
 jitsi-meet-turnserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: enable universe repository then re-install

Comment: there's a distinction between `jitsi` and `jitsi-meet` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a complete uninstall using:

```
apt-get purge jigasi jitsi-meet jitsi-meet-web-config jitsi-meet-prosody jitsi-meet-turnserver jitsi-meet-web jicofo jitsi-videobridge2
```

Then, so a reinstall, using the instructions here:

https://jitsi.org/downloads/ubuntu-debian-installations-instructions/

Specifically:

```
sudo apt-get -y install jitsi-meet
```

from a terminal window.

IMPORTANT: when prompted to input your FQDN for DNS configuration, using something like `meet.jit.si`, not `localhost`.

Here's the URL of the page where I saw this:

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/5053/

Test your installation by loading your browser (e.g., Chrome or Safari) and joining an existing jitsi meeting, or go to meet.jit.si to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apt autoremove
```

Then:

```
apt-get --purge remove jitsi-meet jitsi-meet-web jitsi-meet-prosody jitsi-meet-web-config jicofo jitsi-videobridge
```

This will remove the packages of jitsi, that you do not want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried change prosody config, it is not removed automatically.

1. Delete package about jitsi

`sudo apt purge jigasi jitsi-meet jitsi-meet-web-config jitsi-meet-prosody jitsi-meet-  turnserver jitsi-meet-web jicofo jitsi-videobridge2`

2. Delete dependency package.

`apt autoremove`

2. Delete below two directories.

`/etc/prosody` and `/etc/jitsi`

3. reinstall jitsi package

`apt-get -y install jitsi-meet`

Answer (score -1):

This is a tentative answer intended to be informative and might lead to a solution.  This answer is in the context of [my](https://askubuntu.com/q/1273190/847449) attempts to install the Desktop GUI for `Jitsi` which seems to have its [own](https://superuser.com/q/1576201/977796) problems:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jitsi
```

notably, this error is for `jitsi` (client) rather than `jitsi-meet` (server).

Although even that error isn't fully established.

My speculation is that perhaps the above potential problem has a direct, or even indirect, bearing on the stated problem with installing (or removing) `jitsi-meet` with `apt` as above.

The linked answer is:

> Jitsi's documentation appears to be (currently?) inaccurate. Today the
> `Packages` file downloaded from
> http://download.jitsi.org/stable/Packages in the end provides only
> theses packages (in multiple versions and architectures):
>
> ```
> $ grep-dctrl -F Package -s Package --regex '.*' < Packages | uniq
> Package: jibri
> Package: jicofo
> Package: jigasi
> Package: jitsi-archive-keyring
> Package: jitsi-meet-prosody
> Package: jitsi-meet-tokens
> Package: jitsi-meet-turnserver
> Package: jitsi-meet-web-config
> Package: jitsi-meet-web
> Package: jitsi-meet
> Package: jitsi-upload-integrations
> Package: jitsi-videobridge2
> Package: jitsi-videobridge
> ```
>
> There's no `jitsi` package.
>
> However the `jitsi` package does exist in the [nightly](https://jitsi.org/downloads/) [builds](https://download.jitsi.org/unstable/)
> (reached by replacing the word `stable` with `unstable` in the
> sources.list file).
>
> To be thorough, in April 2020 there was a [snapshot made by
> archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200427072129/https://download.jitsi.org/stable/) of the stable repository, which did include the
> `jitsi` version 2.10.5550-1 package, dated from 2017. So I can only
> conclude that it was removed for some unknown reason from the stable
> repository.
>
> This former missing 2.10 stable package is still available through
> this other Jitsi web page and the linked URL:
>
> https://desktop.jitsi.org/Main/Download.html
>
> https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi/releases/download/Jitsi-2.10/jitsi_2.10.5550-1_amd64.deb
>
> Or else you can add the `jitsi` nightly builds to get the 2.11.x
> versions:
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org unstable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-unstable.list"
> ```
>
> (as the package `jitsi-archive-keyring` is the same in the unstable
> repository and would also install
> `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list` with the stable version
> url, it makes sense to use a different file to avoid it being
> overwritten)
>
> There appears to be some inconsistency between the different methods
> available.
>
> which is provided in the event that, as pointed out, the original
> answer gets deleted or otherwise lost in the shuffle.

Comment: I included the linked answer @user3140225 for reference.  While might not be directly related, it does relate to install `jitsi` with `apt` so could be relevant.  It's more of a comment or suggestion.

Comment: I improved the formatting of your answer a bit (the downvote isn't mine).

Comment: no worries. thx.