# Installing Jitsi from unstable error: The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dependencies

Perhaps the cause of this problem is that `jitsi` Desktop (decidedly not `jitsi-meet`) has unmet dependencies which cannot be easily resolved:

```
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list 
#deb https://download.jitsi.org stable/
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-unstable.list 
deb https://download.jitsi.org unstable/
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.jitsi.org unstable/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
210 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ sudo apt -y install jitsi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jitsi : Depends: libavformat57 but it is not installable or
                  libavformat-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable
         Depends: libavcodec57 but it is not installable or
                  libavcodec-extra57 but it is not installable or
                  libavcodec-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 but it is not installable
         Depends: libavfilter6 but it is not installable or
                  libavfilter-extra6 but it is not installable or
                  libavfilter-ffmpeg5 but it is not installable
         Depends: libavutil55 but it is not installable or
                  libavutil-ffmpeg54 but it is not installable
         Depends: libswscale4 but it is not installable or
                  libswscale-ffmpeg3 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
nicholas $
```

Again, [not](https://askubuntu.com/q/1273190/847449) installing `jitsi-meet` but just `jitsi` for the `SIP` GUI.

Comment: [`libavfilter6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavfilter6) and [`libavfilter-extra6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavfilter-extra6) are only in 18.04 and [`libavfilter-ffmpeg5`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavfilter-ffmpeg5) is only in 16.04. So at least from those set of dependencies, I'd say this thing isn't meant to be installed on anything newer than 18.04

Comment: Check whether the deb entry in the source file is in the correct format?
Eg: 
`deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

Comment: This is likely not a duplicate but **it’s still a bug report** as @muru explained (and extended the reply, together with Zanna, in their comments to [your Meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19296/250300)). And from the formal point of view, there is no _question_ here…

Comment: there is an discussion about this in the official forum: https://community.jitsi.org/t/dependencies-problems-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-20-04/66622

Comment: they describe how to build from sources, which seems the obvious solution.